# Is there any way to figure out that child process was killed with SIGKILL by the kernel when the parent process isn't root

Tags: c, unix, kernel, signals, kill-process

I have a situation where there is a nonroot (so i can't read kernel logs) parent process and its child, the child may have been killed with SIGKILL by the kernel for consuming a lot of memory. When it happens the parent process should know that the child was killed because of exceeding the limit of memory (ideally), but i don't even know whether i can to figure out that it was killed by SIGKILL, not to mention about the reason. So i need to understand from side of parent process whether the child was killed with SIGKILL, and if it was why it happened (but this is second issue).

Can someone give me advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [`wait(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitid.2.html) on the child and use the macro `WIFSIGNALED` to check if it was terminated by a signal.

```
int status = 0;

// wait for child to exit
pid_t child_pid = wait(&status);

if (WIFEXITED(status))
{
    printf("exited with %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
{
    printf("Signaled with %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
}
```

If you have multiple child processes, you can use a loop to wait for them all.

`WTERMSIG(status)` would return the signal number. To figure out the signal, you could check:

```
if (WTERMSIG(status) == SIGKILL) {
    ...
} else if (WTERMSIG(status) == SIGTERM) {
    ...
}
```

There's no way to figure out exactly who sent a kill (whether by the OOM killer or something else e.g., one could do `kill -9 PID` from the shell).
It's reasonable to assume that signals are not sent indiscriminately on a system and that it's usually the kernel itself (OOM killer) that sends `SIGKILL`.

Answer (score 1):

The status provided by `waitXXX( )`[(see man page)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitid.2.html) makes it possible to determine that the child has been killed by a signal:
First check by calling `WIFSIGNALED(wstatus)` if that happened, then you can call `WTERMSIG(wstatus)` to determine the signal number. However you can't determine if the process was killed by the kernel or by another process calling `kill()`.